# Remover "risquinhos" de uma textarea

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma textarea e gostaria de saber como remove estes "risquinhos":
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta adicionar em seu CSS:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Lembrando que isso vai remover o "risquinho" e também desabilitar o redimensionamento do *textarea*.